# Method invoke arguments in array

Tags: java, methods, invoke

I am trying to invoke a method object, for an unknown class, the parameters will be in a string array, how can I pass this as the arguments when invoking a method object?

For example

```
method.invoke(obj, arg1, arg2,...);
```

I have

```
String[] args = {"arg1", "arg2"...}
```

The string array will be different every time depending on user input, thus resulting in different arguments.

Comment: What is the definition of the method?

Comment: Are the contents of the string array names of variables in the real program?  You can't do that.

Comment: Its a different method depending on the user input, I have 5 classes set up with an `execute` method, and depending on user input it will create the corresponding class. These methods all have different parameter types, which I have in a string array, hence the question. @LouisWasserman No.... its the arguments I am trying to pass in.

Comment: So the method you're trying to call takes string arguments?

Answer (score 1):

If the method of that object has only arguments of String or any Compatible type for String you can pass args as whole .
change 
**String[] args = {"arg1", "arg2"...};**
to 
**Object[] args = {"arg1", "arg2"...};**
like this :
**method.invoke(obj, args);**

make sure that when you get the method object : class.getMethod("method", types);
the types arg must match the number and the types of args that you will pass.
for example :
**Class[] types = { String.class, String.class, String.class };**
matches with
**Object[] args = {"arg1", "arg2" ,"arg3"};**
but does not with 
**Object[] args = {"arg1", "arg2};**

dynamic calling

assuming that the methods accepting only Strings (otherwise you need more complex mapping)
psedo code :

Method :

otbtain the method name.

example :print //stored on variable methodName

Args:

get list or array of the user inputs

example : args = {"bla" ,"bla" ...}

Types:

having types arraylist.

for each arg ,Do arraylist.add(String.class)//or any another class if is not a String

Class[] types = {};

types = arraylist.toArray(types);

Now you have all you need call :

someClass.getMethod(methodName ,types).invoke(instanceofSomeClass,args);//this

works what ever arguments the user enters

Comment: I think you are trying to implement runtime interpreter ,if so why do not use Nashorn ,groovy or jython ? those will let you execute code on the fly.
Anyway after I checked ur response to Louis I got a hint to what you want to achieve